# Reading a file in R space separated, skip first lines

Tags: r

I'd like to read a file in R into a matrix of M by N.

The file is of the following form:

```
# /n/home11/tros/sar/tests/mars/abro 250
# /n/home11/tros/sar/tests/mars/abro 230
# /n/home11/tros/sar/tests/mars/abro 20
# /n/home11/tros/sar/tests/mars/abro 20
# T (M rows,N cols)
# M 3
# N 4
7.947363550e+03 1.066183995e+04 3.896434554e+03 8.319875735e+03
1.600281531e+04 1.991086422e+04 1.628421819e+03 1.239507171e+04 
7.430547003e+03 2.349262184e+03 4.883555574e+03 4.986597752e+02
```

The first lines (all lines with # sign) should be skipped, but M and N could (potentially) be read from the header (lines with #) lines.

Then a numeric matrix of dimensions M by N (3 by 4 in this case) should be read, note that the separator is just space (NOT tabs).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read.table` will skip lines starting with `#` by default:

```
s <- "# /n/home11/tros/sar/tests/mars/abro 250
# /n/home11/tros/sar/tests/mars/abro 230
# /n/home11/tros/sar/tests/mars/abro 20
# /n/home11/tros/sar/tests/mars/abro 20
# T (M rows,N cols)
# M 3
# N 4
7.947363550e+03 1.066183995e+04 3.896434554e+03 8.319875735e+03
1.600281531e+04 1.991086422e+04 1.628421819e+03 1.239507171e+04 
7.430547003e+03 2.349262184e+03 4.883555574e+03 4.986597752e+02
"

read.table(header=FALSE, text=s)
##          V1        V2       V3         V4
## 1  7947.364 10661.840 3896.435  8319.8757
## 2 16002.815 19910.864 1628.422 12395.0717
## 3  7430.547  2349.262 4883.556   498.6598
```

Rather than using `text=` you will probably want to use `file=` and supply a file name from which to read the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
Lines <- readLines(s)
M <- as.numeric( sub("^#\\sM" ,"" , Lines[grep("^#\\sM",Lines)]) )
M
#[1] 3
N <- as.numeric( sub("^#\\sN" ,"" , Lines[grep("^#\\sN",Lines)]) )
 dat <- read.table(text=Lines[grep("^[^#]",Lines)]) 
 dat
         V1        V2       V3         V4
1  7947.364 10661.840 3896.435  8319.8757
2 16002.815 19910.864 1628.422 12395.0717
3  7430.547  2349.262 4883.556   498.6598
```